# HTML5 LocalStorage store executable scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, cordova

I am developing hybrid app which contains it's own local html & JS file. However, sometime there would be a need to load some small executable JS scripts and even CSS from server. Currently I am doing it with `$.getScript` and it works fine.

To enable the app to work offline, I am thinking to use Angular cache to store json data and images. However, how can I store executable script maybe with localStorage so that it can be later use in offline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage stores text so you can indeed store JS code (which is just text) there.

You'd just have to load it form LocalStorage and then either execute it with `eval()` or create a `<script>` tag and insert the script into it.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1rLcaroc/

And, the code for that is this:

```
var str = "alert('hello');";

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("code", str);

    var code = localStorage.getItem("code");
    eval(code);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It would be nice with an example to show how it could be done for better understanding.

Comment: @user1995781 - what part do you not understand?  Reading/writing to/from LocalStorage?  Using `eval()`?

Comment: @user1995781 Take a look at the [documentation for `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). There are very few instances in which you should use it.